# Pointers and type casting in C

Tags: c

Suppose I have the following C code

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    float a=3.14;
    char j= a;
    printf("%d\n", j);
    return 0;
}
```

**OUTPUT** :3 (as expected)

Now suppose I do the same thing using pointers.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    float a=3.14;
    char *j= (char*)&a;
    printf("%d\n", *j);
    return 0;
}
```

**OUTPUT** :-61

Now why I am getting **-61** instead of **3**

**EDIT**
From the answers so far, I understood that since char (normally) are of 1 byte long, so a char pointer picks only first byte and gives **-61** instead of printing complete float.

But, here how the compiler determine the  size of data type so that it knows where it has to stop printing.Will it be determined by the pointer type as it seems through answers so far?

But Ideally,during lexical phase of compilation, symbol table is created and the data type is also understood at that time.

**Question**
So, If I say to compiler using a char pointer,"Hey Buddy!! Just print the data (type) that you find at the location pointed by the char pointer given by me.".It should then ,print the complete float as the compiler knows now that its a float.?

Comment: The edit just made this question even more confusing, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first snippet involves a *conversion* of one type to another; when you assign `3.14` to `j`, the compiler changes the representation of the value from float format (`0xc3f54840` on my system) to `char` format (`0x03`).  Remember that when floating-point values are converted to integral values, the fractional part is simply truncated.

In the second snippet, you're changing how you *interpret* the value stored in `a`.  You're passing <strike>a pointer to</strike> the value of the first byte (value `0xc3`).  Since `printf` is a variadic function, it promotes values of type `char` to `int`.  Since the high bit of `0xc3` is set, it sign-extends the value to `0xffffffc3`, which is -65.

For giggles, I wrote the following code to show how different values are represented in memory<sup>1</sup>:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
  float a  = 3.14;
  char  j  = a;
  unsigned char ju = a;
  char *jp = (char *) &a;
  unsigned char *jpu = (unsigned char *) &a;

  union { float a; unsigned char b[sizeof (float)]; } bytes;

  bytes.a = a;

  printf( "a    = %f\n", a );
  printf( "j    = %d\n", j );
  printf( "ju   = %u\n", ju );
  printf( "*jp  = %d (%02x) \n", (char) *jp, (char) *jp );
  printf( "*jpu = %u (%02x) \n", (unsigned char) *jpu, (unsigned char )*jpu );
  printf( "a representation  = " );
  for ( size_t i = 0; i < sizeof bytes.a; i++ )
  {
    printf( "%02x ", bytes.b[i] );
  }
  putchar( '\n' );
  printf( "j representation  = %02x\n", j );
  printf( "ju representation = %02x\n", ju );

  return 0;
}
```

which gave the following results on my system:

```
a    = 3.140000
j    = 3
ju   = 3
*jp  = -61 (ffffffc3)
*jpu = 195 (c3)
a representation  = c3 f5 48 40
j representation  = 03
ju representation = 03
```

---

<sup>1.  I'm technically committing a no-no by reading from different union member than the one I last assigned to; can't remember if this is truly undefined behavior or not.</sup>

Comment: Re: reading member other than last-written-to: It wasn't clear in C99 (it was listed as **Unspecified** Behavior in the non-normative Annex J), but that was a mistake, there was a Defect Report and it was no longer unspecified as of C99-TC3. C11 also changes Annex J to specify _"the value of bytes that correspond to union members other than the last stored into"_ as Unspecified Behavior. Defect Report: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/dr_283.htm

Answer (score 1):

```
char *j= (char*)&a;
```

Now `j` points to the first byte of `a`, which itself is probably four bytes long.

```
printf("%d\n", *j);
```

Here you pass the value of the first byte in the underlying representation of `a`, as an int.

By IEEE 754, this is the first byte of `0x4048f5c3` (check it [here](http://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/)). Assuming your machine is little endian, you get `0xc3`. Your `char` is signed, so you get `0x100-0xc3` =`61`.

---

As to your edit: you do not ask the compiler to print the data type pointed to by your pointer. The only information the compiler can reliably have about the contents of this address is the static type it has, namely a `char`. There is no runtime support for type information in C.

The compiler may, *accidentaly*, know that this memory region happens to be a `float` (because it is smart and/or you gave a degenerated example), But this may only help for warnings and optimizations; How about this identical case?

```
void foo(char* j)
{
    printf("%d\n", *j);
}

// perhaps in a translation unit:

int main()
{
    float a=3.14;
    foo((char*)&a);
    return 0;
}
```

In this case, you explicitly asked him to treat this memory region as a char, so it does exactly that, and has nothing to warn about.

Comment: Don't think it is undefined since `char *` is allowed to alias and the value should just be promoted to `int`.

Comment: So the value is implementation defined?

Comment: I think so ... I am still thinking it over

Comment: The problem is the vararg thing. I am not sure integral promotions happens here.

Answer (score 0):

Because you've gone from a proper type conversion (you should have got warnings about a truncation) to a bit-wise kind of situation.  All bets are off when you just pick the first byte of an in-memory representation without some kind of semantic conversion.

Comment: I am using gcc and surprisingly I didn't get any warning.

Answer (score 0):

You cast pointer, but referred data in the variable "a" still float. So, print is incorrect. You need to cast data before print:

```
printf("%d\n", (int)(*(float*)(void*)j));
```

Comment: Sir, it does the task.

Comment: So... you basically do the following: `(int)*(float*)(void*)(char*)&a`. Congratulations, it is the very same thing as writing `(int)a` in a very very obfuscated way.

Comment: @InsaneCoder It does? So what you were looking for all the time was really just a way to print a float as an int? This code is identical to `printf("%d\n", (int)a);`

Comment: 1. Not obfuscated, just for suppress warnings for g++ compilation options -Wall. 2. Yes, (int)a works, but original question was - how to use casted pointer for print original value.

Answer (score 0):

Here a description of the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    float a=3.14;
```

You declare a variable `a` of type `float` and put 3.14 inside, which is 0x4048f5c3 according to IEEE754 representation of float numbers. (http://www.binaryconvert.com/result_float.html?decimal=051046049052)
So basically, in memory, you have 4 bytes: 0x4048f5c3

```
    char *j= (char*)&a;
```

You declare a pointer that points to the first byte of `a` which contains 0xc3 (depending on the internal representation of bytes of your system). Since `j` is a `char*`, you forget about all the other bytes.

```
    printf("%d\n", *j);
```

0xc3 is -61 for a signed char (http://www.binaryconvert.com/result_signed_char.html?decimal=045054049)

```
    return 0;
}
```

However, when in the first case you wrote `char j = a;`, `a` was properly casted.

And of course, if you cast `j` into a `float*`, you can access to the full number:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    float a=3.14;
    char *j= (char*)&a;
    printf("%d\n", *j);

    printf("%f\n", *((float*)j));

    return 0;
}
```

Will print:

```
-61
3.140000
```

Answer (score 0):

Value of a floating point variable should be interpreted using floating point instructions, because it is stored in memory using some floating point standards like [IEEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point).

But typecasting to **char *** will interpret it using general integer instructions & which doesn't aware of the notation, so result is undefined.

Typecasting to **char** will lead to use the floating point to integer conversion instruction and the result will be the mantissa part of the floating point variable(unless it overflows the destination variable size)